# symfony не хочет создавать файлы после переноса httpd+php

Tags: php, linux, centos, symfony, apache2.4

> [Mon Dec 10 09:48:14.553353 2018] [:error] [pid 19077] [client] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/vhosts/workshop.app/app/cache/prod)\n' in /var/www/vhosts/workshop.app/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2671\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/workshop.app/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2632): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer()\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/workshop.app/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2411): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/workshop.app/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2442): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/workshop/app.php(28): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/workshop.app/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2671

Апач работает под правами apache:apache

php5.6

права на папку ставил и 777 владелец естественно apache, но при этом полностью отказывается писать все в эту папку.
куда смотреть, куда копать не понятно

**UPD1 Конфиг HTTPD**

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "domain.ru:80"
    ServerAlias "www.domain.ru"
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/workshop.app/web"


 <Directory /var/www/vhosts/workshop.app/web>

      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
      #    Options FollowSymlinks
</Directory>
```

Comment: На всякий случай уточню, права вы ставили на папку **/var/www/vhosts/workshop.app/app/cache/**?

Comment: на всю папку /var/www/vhosts/workshop.app и ниже лежащие.  ставил и по уму на файлы 644 на папки 755, главное владелец апач:апач, не завелось, 777 думаю в любом случае должно завестись, но не завелось.

Comment: Попробуйте в web/app.php и web/app_dev.php дописать, раскоментить в начале файла umask(0000);

Comment: та же ошибка. ничего не поменялось.

Comment: А php как модуль запускается или в режиме fcgi? Если как модуль, то чет даж не знаю в чем может быть проблема, если fcgi то у php свой пользователь

Comment: вроде как модуль, не fpm, как точно проверить?)

Comment: В настройках vhost апача посмотреть

Comment: выложил конфиг httpd

Comment: а вы создали собственно папку `/var/www/vhosts/workshop.app/app/cache`? Она не под гитом и возможно не была создана автоматически

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем разобрался сам. оказывается SELinux блокировал запись в папку.

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/
```

И все. спасибо всем кто помогал разбираться.